# SELECT Numbers,Numbers AND str in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table in mysql that contain two columns at the coumn of contracts have three type of data number,string and(number&string together) how I can select only numbers and the fields that contain number&string without returning fields that only string by using regular expression the above is a capture of my table  [image: my table]

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: With that table data, what's the expected result?

Comment: What have you tried so far?. Please attach it..

Comment: ...and try something. Given that there are only 10 numbers, I almost think you could figure this out for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have

```
select * from contracts where contracts REGEXP '.*[0-9].*'
```